# запрос на откат даты поста на сайте mysql

Tags: mysql, запрос

Здравствуйте. Можно ли сгенерировать sql запрос таким образом, чтобы все сообщения на форуме были датированы 2011 годом? Форум основан на mybb.

За посты отвечает колонка mybb_posts, либо же mybb_forums целиком. Также, если возможность присутствует, подскажите как менять дату регистрации пользователя? Пользователи записаны в колонке mybb_users

Comment: "О, брат! Это жулики. Они замышляют зловещее преступление на крыше" (с) Карлсон

Comment: Да, на локалхосте!

Comment: А каким годом они датированы сейчас?

Comment: Интересует сырой `Update` запрос? `UPDATE mybb_posts SET dateline = dateline - 31864500` - это минус год.

Comment: Сегодняшним числом (15/02/17) пару часов назад. Я лишь проверяю действие плагинов и саму работу движка. Все сообщения я пишу сам с созданных мною аккаунтов, чтобы форум казался не таким пустым. И что подразумевается под сырым запросом?

Comment: Под сырым запросом, я подразумеваю, что вы его будете выполнять вручную, без php.

Comment: Да, все так. Спасибо большое, заработало. Регистрация пользователей тоже таким же способом как я понял. Вот только как конвертировать для определенной даты? Онлайн сервисы подскажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно всем выставить точную дату:

```
UPDATE mybb_posts SET dateline = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-04-01 13:00:00');
```

Если нужно отнять год, можно так и сделать:

```
UPDATE mybb_posts SET dateline = dateline - 31864500/*~секунд в году*/;
```

По поводу структуры базы, лучше всего смотреть [документацию](https://docs.mybb.com/1.6/Database-Tables-mybb-posts/) к движку.

Comment: Спасибо! 7 символ